# Prove that $f^{-1}(Y \setminus B_1) = X \setminus f^{-1}(B_1)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f:X \to Y$ be a map with $A_1,A_2 \subset X$ and $B_1,B_2 \subset Y$. Prove that $f^{-1}(Y \setminus B_1) = X \setminus f^{-1}(B_1)$ where $f^{-1}(B) = \{x \in X: f(x) \in B\}$.

**Attempt:**

Let $y \in f^{-1}(Y \setminus B_1)$. Then there exists an $x \in Y \setminus B_1$ such that $f^{-1}(x) = y$. Thus, $y \in f^{-1}(Y \cap B_1') = f^{-1}(Y) \cap f^{-1}(B_1')$.

What do I do from here?

Comment: What is $f^{-1}(x)$? Did you mean to say $f(y)=x$?

Comment: @sqtrat No, I meant $f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: How do you define $f^{-1}(x)$, is this the pre-image $f^{-1}(\{x\})$?

Answer (score 2):

$x \in f^{-1}(Y\setminus B)\Leftrightarrow f(x) \in Y\setminus B\Leftrightarrow f(x)\notin B\Leftrightarrow x\in X=f^{-1}(Y)$ and $x \notin f^{-1}(B)\Leftrightarrow x \in f^{-1}(Y)\setminus f^{-1}(B)=X\setminus f^{-1}(B). $