# Show that $f^{-1}(Y\setminus B_{1})=X\setminus f^{-1}(B_{1})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to do this question based on [sqtrat](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1803532)'s answer, but I am having trouble understanding their answer based on mine.

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a map and let $B_{1}\subset Y$. Show that $f^{-1}(Y\setminus B_{1})=X\setminus f^{-1}(B_{1})$.

Let $x\in f^{-1}(Y\setminus B_{1})$. Then there exists a $y\in Y\setminus B_{1}$ such that $f^{-1}(y)=x$. Then $y\in Y$ and $y\notin B_{1}$. Then $x\in X$ and $x\notin f^{-1}(B_{1})$.

> The part I do not understand: why is $f^{-1}(Y)=X$? Because the function is bijective due to it having an inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity $f^{-1}(Y)=X$ is always true for any function $f:X \rightarrow Y$, and is in fact a trivial statement.

If $x\in X$ then $f(x) \in Y$ hence $x \in f^{-1}(Y)$. Thus, $X \subset f^{-1}(Y)$.

But certainly, we also have $f^{-1}(Y) \subset X$ by definition of the inverse image.

The equality follows.

NB: For any function, we can define the inverse image of a subset of the target space, and we use the symbol $f^{-1}$ for it. It must not be mixed with the notation $f^{-1}$ that represents the inverse function of a bijection. In order to distinguish both of them, just look at the nature of the argument. The "inverse image" symbol takes *subsets* of the target space as argument, whereas the inverse function of a bijection takes *elements* of the target space as argument.

Comment: I see, I see. I totally forgot that the inverse image is different from the inverse of a function. :~) Thanks for pointing it out and answering fast in a clear and understandable way.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

x in $f^{-1}$(Y - B) iff f(x) in Y - B
iff f(x) in Y and f(x) not in B iff
x in X and x not in $f^{-1}$(A) iff
x in X - $f^{-1}$(A).